# Time invariace of a linear system dependent on a particular time instant

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

$$y[n]=x[n]+35*x[n-1]+x[0]$$

Is this system time invariant? I am under the impression that $x[0]$ can be considered a constant. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time-invariant system reacts to a shifted input by an equal shift in its response, i.e. if $y[n]$ is the system's response to $x[n]$, then for the system to be time-invariant, its response to $x[n-k]$ must be $y[n-k]$ for some integer $k$.

Now let's assume that $y[n]$ is the response to $x[n]$ and let's see what happens if we use $x_1[n]=x[n-k]$ as an input signal:

$$y_1[n]=x_1[n]+35x_1[n-1]+x_1[0]=x[n-k]+35x[n-k-1]+x[-k]$$

which is not equal to $y[n-k]$, so the system is not time-invariant.

Comment: The system is indeed linear in the sense that 
$$
y\{a x_1[n] + x_2[n] \} = 
ay\{x_1[n]\} + y\{x_2[n]\}
$$
which is what linear usually means in this context.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I've changed my answer. I fell in the same trap as the OP by somehow seeing $x[0]$ as a constant. If $x[0]$ were replaced by some constant $c$, then the system would indeed be time-invariant but non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "$x[0]$ can be considered a constant".

At any rate, this system is definitely not time invariant.  Try feeding in $x[n] = \delta[n]$, shifting it over time, and seeing what happens.

In particular, putting in $x[n-1]$ does **not** give you $y[n-1]$, which is the property that defines time-invariance.

Comment: You wanted to say "definitely not *time-invariant*".